# My attempt at creating a Carnatic music producing computer

Tags: python-3.x, random

I am trying to create a Carnatic kalpana-swara making machine as a Margazhi special with a base code with the knowledge I have. I have built it in Python 3.11.x and I have got a working, albeit primitive, model, as below.

```py
def sing_swaras(pattern):
    arohanam = "SRGPDS"
    avarohanam = "SDPGRS"

    swaras = {'S': 'sa', 'R': 'ri', 'G': 'ga', 'P': 'pa', 'D': 'da'}

    mel_sthayi = ''.join([swaras[swara] for swara in arohanam])
    keel_sthayi = ''.join([swaras[swara] for swara in avarohanam])

    melody = mel_sthayi + keel_sthayi

    result = []
    for char in pattern:
        if char.upper() in swaras:
            result.append(swaras[char.upper()])
    return (' '.join(result))+' sannuthaangasri...'

while True:
    user_input = input("Vidwan: ").lower()
    if user_input == 'sannuthaangasri':
        print("""
GR,S, RS,D, SD,P, G | RSDP ,RSD PG,S DPGR ||
SR,GR G,PGP ,DSR, G | PD,R G,PD S,GP ,DSR ||
GRSRS DSDPG ,R,SD P | ,R,S ,DPG ,S,D ,PGR ||
Sannuthaangasri nivaasaa... sannuthaangasri...""")
        break

    python_response = sing_swaras(user_input.split()[0])
    print("Python:", python_response)
```

A sample output goes as follows:

```
Vidwan: grgpdpgrgrsdpdsr sannuthaangasri
Python: ga ri ga pa da pa ga ri ga ri sa da pa da sa ri sannuthaangasri...
Vidwan: rsdp|rsgr|gpgr|sdpg|rsdp|grsr|dssr|dssr sannuthaangasri...
Python: ri sa da pa ri sa ga ri ga pa ga ri sa da pa ga ri sa da pa ga ri sa ri da sa sa ri da sa sa ri sannuthaangasri...
Vidwan: sannuthaangasri

GR,S, RS,D, SD,P, G | RSDP ,RSD PG,S DPGR ||
SR,GR G,PGP ,DSR, G | PD,R G,PD S,GP ,DSR ||
GRSRS DSDPG ,R,SD P | ,R,S ,DPG ,S,D ,PGR ||
Sannuthaangasri nivaasaa... sannuthaangasri...
```

My problems with the above code are:

1. It is right now reproducing what I write. I don't want that to happen. Rather I am trying to make the computer 'think' on its own and produce its own patterns. I could use `random` module but again it is cumbersome.
2. I want the compiler to place commas for some swaras. It produces none as of now. Commas convey a special meaning in Carnatic music - they indicate that you have to sustain on that note. This also is a subset of the above problem.

Would appreciate clues for me to build on this interface. (It must NOT be a GUI, it is best off this method.)